# Can I use a US-bought chandelier in India?

Tags: lighting

I am planning to buy a chandelier in the US for my home in India.  I understand the voltage difference (110 V in the US as compared to 220 V in India).

The chandelier uses 60 Watt candelabra bulbs.  So, I was wondering if I can use this chandelier in India with 60 Watts / 220V candelabra bulbs?

Comment: See this post for concerns about using a 110V device on 220V wiring: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10101/can-i-safely-use-a-switch-rated-for-1a-at-125v-with-240v-assuming-i-stay-bel

Answer (score 3):

If the chandelier is simply controlled by a wall switch (i.e. no internal electronics), it should be safe to do so because you'll be using bulbs that draw about half the current that the wiring in the chandelier can supply: 60 W / 110 V bulb will draw approximately 550 mA from the US electrical supply, whereas a 60 W / 220 V bulb will draw approximately 270 mA from the Indian electrical supply.

However, if the chandelier has an integral dimmer, then it probably won't work with the different supply voltage and frequency.

Comment: I'd wonder if the insulation on the wiring within the chandelier is adequate for 220V.

Comment: @BMitch: lamp wire is often rated for 300 V

Comment: While you are right that one can often get away with this, it is horrible advice to give.  The real problem is heat.  When someone uses the wrong bulb **and they will**, the lamp will be subjected to up to 4 times as much heat as it could expect to see at its design voltage.  This will lead to insulation breakdown and electrocution and/or fire. ...  
Also, lamp wire is not always rated for 300V and it is not the only part of the lamp where designers and testers assume they need only handle 120V.